# 'DisabledBackend' object has no attribute '_get_task_meta_for' redis backend problem?

Tags: redis, celery, django-celery, celery-task

I made a django project and going to use celery for asnc tasks.

I set up the celery backend like below and redis-cli MONITOR shows the data is being deal with normally.

```
celery config in settings.py
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://localhost:6379/1'
CELERY_RESULT_PERSISTENT = True
CELERY_RESULT_PERSISTENT_BACKEND = 'redis'
```

redis-cli MONITOR When starting task

```
1680859906.824453 [0 127.0.0.1:51706] "SELECT" "1"
1680859906.824743 [1 127.0.0.1:51706] "GET" "celery-task-meta-36852709-41ee-4dd0-b8b1-7e50376647ec"
1680859906.825289 [1 127.0.0.1:51706] "MULTI"
1680859906.825311 [1 127.0.0.1:51706] "SETEX" "celery-task-meta-36852709-41ee-4dd0-b8b1-7e50376647ec" "86400" "{\"status\": \"SUCCESS\", \"result\": null, \"traceback\": null, \"children\": [], \"date_done\": \"2023-04-07T09:31:46.823431\", \"task_id\": \"36852709-41ee-4dd0-b8b1-7e50376647ec\"}"
1680859906.825365 [1 127.0.0.1:51706] "PUBLISH" "celery-task-meta-36852709-41ee-4dd0-b8b1-7e50376647ec" "{\"status\": \"SUCCESS\", \"result\": null, \"traceback\": null, \"children\": [], \"date_done\": \"2023-04-07T09:31:46.823431\", \"task_id\": \"36852709-41ee-4dd0-b8b1-7e50376647ec\"}"
1680859906.825410 [1 127.0.0.1:51706] "EXEC"
```

celery starting status

```
- ** ---------- [config]
- ** ---------- .> app:         project_django:0x7f99c9fa1470
- ** ---------- .> transport:   amqp://guest:**@localhost:5672//
- ** ---------- .> results:     redis://localhost:6379/1
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 24 (prefork)
-- ******* ---- .> task events: OFF (enable -E to monitor tasks in this worker)
--- ***** ----- 
 -------------- [queues]
                .> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery
```

but when I'm accessing to task.backend or status, this attribute error always occur!

```
task = my_task.apply_async(args=(key,), backend='redis://localhost:6379/1')
    backend = AsyncResult(task.id).backend
```

<celery.backends.base.DisabledBackend object at 0x7f7b9444cfd0>

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: I think my redis server seems habving problem.
When I set the broker url to redis, redis cli shows transporting task is pending..